# Trying to get input from the user and display something in python but it gives me an error

Tags: python

I am making a program just to test if I can get input from a user and display their input. I looked online on how to do it and I copied it and put it on my program but it gives me an error that says this,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Home/PycharmProjects/untitled/j.py", line 1, in <module>
    a = input("enter your name")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'hi' is not defined
```

Here is my code,

```
a = input("enter your name")

print(a)
```

May you please help me on this? Thank you.

This is not a duplicate I didn't even know there were other people that asked this question.

Comment: You are using Python 2.x and `input()` tries to evaluate what you type in. Use `raw_input()` instead.

Comment: Thank you, TessellatingHeckler. It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

a = raw_input('Enter your name')

print a

However the raw_input does not exist in Python 3.x.
[What's the difference between raw_input() and input() in python3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x)